# Todo.App is used in Todo.UWP.MainPage but who invokes Todo.UWP.App?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

I created a brand new Xamarin.Forms solution consisting of 2 projects:

- NET Standard shared project called `Todo`
- UWP project called `Todo.UWP`

Both projects have `App` and `MainPage` classes.

I only know that `Todo.App` is invoked in the `Todo.UWP.MainPage` as follows.

```
LoadApplication(new Todo.App());
```

I am wondering what the purpose of `Todo.UWP.App` is because I have not noticed any part of the source code that instantiates it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering what the purpose of Todo.UWP.App is because I have not noticed any part of the source code that instantiates it.

It's designed by Xamarin Forms Application ,it not directly load `MainPage`in `Todo.UWP`.Because Xamarin forms is a cross-platform solution ,it should consider other platforms how to lauch such as `iOS` or `Android` . It's app lifecycle shows as follow :

- **UWP** – *Main method > App(UWP) > MainPage(UWP) > App > ContentPage*

If contains other platforms (**iOS and Android** ):

- iOS – Main method > AppDelegate > App > ContentPage
- Android – MainActivity > App > ContentPage

Each of them needs to load `App` from Froms Solution, here is `Todo.App()` .Refer to [this official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/building-cross-platform-applications/understanding-the-xamarin-mobile-platform) to understand more about Xamarin Forms

If not needs a Xamarin Forms Solution , you can create a **Xamarin.UWP** Solution that only contain a `UWP` project .Next time creating a new Project , select follow type to create :
[image]

Then the content of solution is:

[image]

Here the App lifecycle is : *Main method > App > Page* .

Comment: Where is the `Main` method? I don't see it.

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer The `Main` method is, by default, auto generated and not visible in the code. UWP is the same with WPF ,you can see it in document :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/desktop/lifecycle#app-lifecycle

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer Oh, I also have no idea about showing it ...

Comment: OK. Thanks for this discussion. :-)